# setState not working- React Native maps does not display user current location

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-maps

```
  const [initialPosition,setInitialPosition] = useState({
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
  })
  
  const locateCurrentPosition=() => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position =>{
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(position));
        let currentLocation={
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }
       setInitialPosition(currentLocation);
      //  console.log(initialPosition);
      }
    )
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    locateCurrentPosition();
  },[])
```

setInitialPosition(currentLocation); does not update state value and returns 0 for latitude and longitude. Hence current location is not being displayed in the app instead it's displaying (0,0) location on app launch. Kindly help me. If any other snippet of code is required do let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this example:

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const [latitude,setlatitude] = useState(0);
const [longitude,setlongitude] = useState(0);
const [coordinates,setcoordinates] = useState([]);

const locateCurrentPosition=() => {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position =>{
              setlatitude(position.coords.latitude);
              setlongitude(position.coords.longitude);
            },
          )
      }

useEffect(()=>{
        locateCurrentPosition();
      },[])

<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <MapView
                style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%" }}
                region={{
                    latitude: latitude,
                    longitude: longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}
                >
                <MapView.Marker
                    coordinate={{
                        latitude: latitude,
                        longitude: longitude,
                      }}
                />
                </MapView>
      </View>
```